# microsoft search using multiple criteria (wildcards, exclusions, etc.)

Tags: search, axapta

I am using a Microsoft DB application (AXAPTA) that lets us search various fields by typing criteria at the tops of the table.  An example would be to filter item numbers to those starting with a 2 by typing 2* or excluding items with bell in the description by typing !bell.  Quotes are not normally needed.  We often combine multiple criteria by separating them with a "," For example, 2*,9* where the "," acts as an OR.  Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to create a multiple criteria AND.  What I am trying to do is exclude items that have DNU in the description AND also have bell in the description.

My thought would be 
!*DNU* & bell 
but that doesn't work.  Any ideas?  I am sure this is simple, but I am stuck.

Comment: I haven't been able to get &, AND, or any " " criteria to work in the search.

Comment: For whatever reason, _*bell*,!*DNU*_  works but _!*DNU*,*bell*_ does not.  Maybe inclusions need to come before exclusions?  I don't know, but that is how I got it to work.

Comment: I'm assuming it just does `str2con()` or something similar, then loops through each string and adds each as a range in order. So that's why one way would work and not the other.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the advanced SQL query syntax, which can also be put in the filter location.

You'll have to play with it a while to get exactly what you want, but see these links below. You'll probably need to use a combination of info from the different links:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa569937.aspx

http://www.axaptapedia.com/Expressions_in_query_ranges

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa893981.aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/fin-and-ops/get-started/advanced-filtering-query-options